# React useState changes all elements in an array in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 states product and variations I call an API and set the values of both state to the API response.

I want the product state to stay as it is and not update

```
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({} as any);
  const [variations, setVariations] = useState([] as any);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      const data = await axios.get("/products?id=4533843820679");
      console.log(data);
      setProduct(data.data);
      // @ts-ignore
      setVariations([data.data]);
    };
    getProduct();
  }, []);
```

In return I map the variations array and return inputs for title, and price and a button to add variations. Adding variations will add another product to variations array. So it just pushes product to variations.

Then I have inputs for title in variation and prices in variation.variants. The problem is with onChange.

When I change the price of one element in variants it changes for all and also changes it for PRODUCT state.

The code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-firefly-6n747?file=/src/App.js

Add variations, change prices add another variations and you'll see all issues I'm facing.

Comment: In your CodeSandbox example, you aren't deep-copying the product, so the `variants` array is shared between the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this:

```
 variant.price = e.target.value; // same issue with title
```

the `variant` object reference is **shared** among variations and you are modifying it directly. It is shared because you you made a shallow copy of a `variation` using `...` when adding it.

Here is the solution:

You should update the specific `variant` object in **immutable** way (in react you should always update state in immutable way). For that you need to use this as `onChange` for `price`:

```
onChange = {
    (e) => {
        let updated = variations.map((x) => {
            if (x.id === variation.id) {
                return {
                    ...x,
                    variants: x.variants.map((y) => {
                        if (y.id === variant.id) {
                            return {
                                ...y,
                                price: e.target.value
                            };
                        }
                        return y;
                    })
                };
            }
            return x;
        });
        setVariations(updated);
    }
}
```

This for `onChange` for `title`:

```
onChange = {
    (e) => {
        let updated = variations.map((x) => {
            if (x.id === variation.id) {
                return {
                    ...x,
                    title: e.target.value
                };
            }
            return x;
        });
        setVariations(updated);
    }
}
```

**NOTE** but ids of variations must be different. For testing purposes you can use this as click handler when adding a new variation:

```
onClick = {
    () => {
        setVariations((prev) => [...prev, {
            ...product,
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) // for testing
        }]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not pushing the product to variations. You are overwriting it.

To push a value to array with useState,

```
setVariations([...variations, product])
```

But, if you change the product object, variations also gonna be change because it's the same object. (Maybe, react not gonna re-render it but trust me, it is changed.) If you want to keep it same you need to create new object.

So,

```
setProduct(data.data);
setVariations([...variations, {...data.data}]);
```

Now, you can change **product**. variations not gonna change.

Answer (score -1):

This was because you did a shallow copy of an object.

Try to do like this:

```
setVariations([...variations, data.data,]);
```